# Does BufferedWriter's write(String S) method actually buffer?

Tags: java, performance, java-8, file-handling, bufferedwriter

As per the [Java SE 8 Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html), the BufferedWriter class has the following methods of its own(w.r.t writing data):

```
write(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)
write(int c)
write(String s, int off, int len)
```

As I confirmed from checking the source code of this class, it does not override Writer's `write(String s)` method. It simply inherits it.

My question is, given the following code:

```
public static void SaveTextToFile(String fileName, String data, boolean append) throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(fileName)));
        bw.write(data);
        bw.close();
    }
```

Will the data be actually buffered before writing to a file? If not, in which scenarios does the buffering occur?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`write(String str)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write-java.lang.String-) in `Writer` calls [`write(String str, int off, int len)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write-java.lang.String-int-int-), which *is* overridden in [`BufferedWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write-java.lang.String-int-int-). So your data will be buffered.

Comment: Effective Java Item 17

Comment: Thanks! Followed the method calls in the library. Checks out!

Answer (score 2):

Reasoning about which method `BufferedWriter` overrides is pointless. *All* non-abstract methods of the `Writer` class are implemented in terms of other methods, to finally end up at one of the abstract methods, as the `Writer` itself does not implement any actual writing logic (how could it?).

Since `Writer` does not have any notion of a delegation target, it’s impossible to have any method delegating to the target writer without interception by the `BufferedWriter` subclass, as only that subclass knows the target. So all `write` methods, as well as the `append` methods, are under the `BufferedWriter`’s control and will buffer, if the the data to be written is smaller than the buffer’s capacity.

That said, in your example,

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(fileName)));
bw.write(data);
bw.close();
```

there is no advantage in buffering, as the buffer will be flushed right in the subsequent `close()` operation. So in the best case, the `data` in larger than the buffer and you have just unnecessarily created a `BufferedWriter` instance. But if `data` is smaller than the buffer, you have also performed an unnecessary copy operation from `data` to the buffer, before the data gets actually written.

For writing a single item, there is no sense in buffering. Besides that, it is quiet dangerous to offer an `append` parameter that is actually ignored, pretending a functionality that is not there, especially when this can result in unintended overwriting of existing data in the target file. Further, you should use the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html) construct to safely close the writer:

```
public static void SaveTextToFile(String fileName, String data, boolean append)
                                                                throws IOException {
    try(Writer w = new FileWriter(fileName, append)) {
        w.write(data);
    }
}
```

or

```
// use StandardOpenOption.APPEND to append
public static void SaveTextToFile(String fileName, String data, OpenOption... o)
                                                                throws IOException {
    Files.write(Paths.get(fileName),
                Collections.singleton(data), Charset.defaultCharset(), o);
}
```

<sup>which may render your method obsolete, as it only delegates to an already existing method</sup>